# "The Original Data and the Duplicated Data" Versus "the Original and Duplicated Data"

Tags: conjunctions

I already saw these expressions here and there but wonder whether there is a smoother one in this case.

> The original data, which have variables W and X, are from the first source. The duplicated data, which have variables Y and Z, are from the second source. *The original data and the duplicated data* show similar results.

I think *The original and duplicated data* and *The original and the duplicated data* are also possible but don't know whether they are better.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'The original and duplicated data'
2. 'The original and the duplicated data'

Of these 2 modified ones, the 2nd one is clearer and equivalent to the original example.

The 1st one is not advisable.  Though in this case it may not cause confusions, this structure may confuse in other situations, like

1. 'The red and white crowds'
2. 'The red and the white crowds'

Original
'The red crowds and the white crowds'

Example 2 is equivalent to the original.  Example 1 is unclear.

Edit to answer further questions.

a) When equal adjectives are involved for a single item,  like 'The red, white crowds', we sometimes construct the way as in example 1:

'The red and white crowds'

There is just 1 type of crowds.

In 'The original and duplicated data', there are 2 separate sets of data.

The structure, however, is the same as my crowd example.  This may cause confusion although not in this instance.

b) example 2 is quite clear and unlikely to cause confusions.

c) whenever possible, it is good to make sentences concise, subject to personal preference.

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder (a) whether 1 is anyway incorrect even in this case (nevertheless inadvisable), (b) whether 2 leaves zero possibility of errors, unlike 1, and (c) whether native speakers prefer 2 to the non-reduced OP version or vice versa.